# Measuring CPU efficiency of bare metal ARM Cortex A9 system

Tags: arm, cpu-usage, bare-metal

I have a bare metal program implemented on on of the core of the ARM-Cortex A9 processor. The program will be handling 2 interrupts. Now i would like to measure the efficiency of this CPU. May be the ratio of the time the CPU is idle to the time the CPU is busy. I am using a zedboard  (zynq 7000 series) for my  measurements.

Since i do not have a operating system running on the core, i am now aware on how to get CPU efficiency.

Cheers,
S

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to define what you mean by idle.  And that definition for the most part answers your question.

if for example, all the work is in the interrupts, and the foreground task is by definition, when the processor is idling, then you can just measure that or at least relatively.  For example you could have the foreground task, have a counter in a loop that counts and polls the timer, every some X number of timer ticks see how many counts (loops) have completed.  the fewer counts the more time the interrupts occurred, the more counts the less time the interrupts occurred.

Bottom line though, once you define what idle is, you simply take that idle code and measure how long you spend in idle and how long you dont.  Do an experiment with all other tasks off and see, using your measuring stick, what idles performance is with nothing else going on so that when other stuff is running, you can say it is 10% or 50% or whatever.